# Repeater in asp.net from DB with DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, database, repeater

I'm having a problem with a repeater:

1: I have a table with hours: 7:00 , 7:15, 7:30 , ... , and i use a repeater to read all of them and put days and buttons, here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptTable_ItemCommand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Horario</th>
                                                <th>Lunes</th>
                                                <th>Martes</th>
                                                <th>Miércoles</th>
                                                <th>Jueves</th>
                                                <th>Viernes</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><%# Eval("HorarioP") %></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnlunes" runat="server" CommandName="turnolunes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("HorarioP") %>'>Dar Turno</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnmartes" runat="server" CommandName="turnomartes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("HorarioP") %>'>Dar Turno</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnmiercoles" runat="server" CommandName="turnomiercoles" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("HorarioP") %>'>Dar Turno</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnjueves" runat="server" CommandName="turnojueves" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("HorarioP") %>'>Dar Turno</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnviernes" runat="server" CommandName="turnoviernes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("HorarioP") %>'>Dar Turno</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

This looks like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Mzd.png)

I need to filter these repeater by a dropdownlist (out of the repeater) to see different tables for differents medics (like a diary) and i need tu change the button to view turn or give turn (if have free scheduler or occupied scheduler).

I have two tables called medics and turns.

I need to do something like this, when i change the medic i need to see the free and occupied schedulers:

[Filter by Medic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoC1J.png)

Where green buttons are free schedule and red buttons are occupied schedule.

The question is:

¿How i can analize in the repeater button by button in every day and hour if a medic have or dont have free schedule? I have a GetTurnsByMedic method; this returns all turns for a medic in a List.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using ItemDataBound method could give you solution.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server" 
            OnItemDataBound="rptTable_ItemDataBound">


protected void rptTable_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.AlternatingItem) || e.Item.ItemType.Equals(ListItemType.Item))
        {
            //Call your method and do whatever you need to do here
            //You can hide/show disable/enable your buttons
            Button button = e.Item.FindControl("buttonID") as Button;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes! this solve my problem! I can handle all items that i need in ItemDataBound! Thanks!